# Only 192.168.0.3 can request most files, but anyone can request /public/file.html

Tags: networking, apache-2.2

I have the following virtual host on my development server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/web/example.com/pub
    <Directory /srv/web/example.com/pub>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 192.168.0.3
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Allow from 192.168.0.3` part is to only allow requests from my workstation machine.

I want to tweak this to allow anyone to request a certain URL:

```
http://example.com/public/file.html
```

How do I change this to allow `/public/file.html` requests to get through from anyone?

Note: `/public/file.html` doesn't actually exist as a file on the server. I redirect all incoming requests through a single index file using `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, mod_rewrite has nothing to do with physical directories, matched by `<Directory>`. So if you're rewriting `/public/file.html` to a file outside `/srv/web/example.com/pub`, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only way that I found to fix it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/web/example.com/pub
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/public/file.html" public
    <Directory /srv/web/example.com/pub>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.3
        Allow from env=public
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put something like this before (but maybe after) the `<Directory>` block.

```
<LocationMatch "^/public/file.html">
 Satisfy Any
 Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

I am not 100% sure about the order of operations when looking at permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this: (not tested)

```
<Location /public/file.html>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from All
  (Your mod_rewrite stuff)
</Location>
```